# Es posible validar que un campo sea solo numérico exceptuando tres usuarios

Tags: laravel

Estoy utilizando Laravel UI/Auth para el registro y login de los usuarios, cambié la opción de email por username para el login, pero me gustaría saber si es posible validar que el username sea un número (Documento de identidad) para los usuarios finales de la plataforma, pero con la excepción que el administrador (Admin), el operador (Operator) y el Bloglero (Blogger) puedan iniciar sesión con el nombre de usuario que contiene contiene caracteres y son los que se encuentran en paréntesis?

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'username' => ['required', 'numeric', 'max:255'], // <--- Aquí
        'phone' => ['required', 'string','max:255'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'user_type' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Sí, se puede. Tendrías que chequear que el valor del username no sea un numero, si no es número, identificar al usuario que está haciendo el login (consulta la bd con el username), chequear que el usuario no sea admin, operator o blogger, y si no es uno de esos, lanzar el error de validación. Creo que toda esa logica la podrias meter en una custom rule https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-validation-rules, o hacer una funcion anonima en el array de validación

Comment: coloqué la posible respuesta guiandome por tu sugerencia, ¿estaría bien así? No había pensado en que podría en un fututo agregar más operadores o bloggers, pero en caso que se dé el requerimiento, será agregarlos manualmente a los condicionales.

Comment: Sí, creo que puede ir bien así si cumple tu requerimiento

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías utilizar [regex](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-regex):

```
'username' => ['required', 'regex:/^(\d+|Admin|Operator|Blogger)$/'],
```

Esa expresión regular busca cualquier string que empiece y termine siendo un número, o literalmente las palabras "Admin", "Operator" o "Blogger". Es sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas, si no querés que lo sea agregale el operator "i" al final: `$/i']`.

Podés ver bien lo que hace desde acá: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xrH32y/1)

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfectamente... Ahora me queda otra duda, podría a la expresión regular agregarle que el Operator y el Blogger puedan ser, Operator01, Operator 02, así al menos hasta 10 igual al Blogger? en caso que se requieran registrar más usuarios de ese tipo y el sistema lo acepte para el login automaticamente?, sino lo que haría es agregarlos manualmente a medida que sea necesario.

Comment: En la Web hice una prueba y funciona `^(\d+|Admin|Operator\d+|Blogger\d+)$`

Comment: Lo que hiciste es correcto, pero pasa a ser obligatorio que "Operator" tenga un número. Si puede haber un "Operator" sin número tenés que poner: `Operator\d*`. El asterisco significa que puede no haber un número, el `+` que tiene que haber al menos 1.

Answer (score 1):

Tomando en cuenta tu sugerencia (porloscerros) hice lo siguiente:

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    if(is_numeric($request['username']))
    {
        $request->validate([
        $this->username() => 'required|numeric',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }
    elseif($request['username'] == 'Admin' or $request['username'] == 'Operator' or $request['username'] == 'Blogger')
    {
        $request->validate([
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Pero esto lo hice directamente en el archivo `AuthenticatesUsers` no pude sobrescribir el método en el archivo `LoginController`, ¿estaría bien? me funciona, ahora solo debo hacer el condicional en la validación que tengo en Livewire, ya que se muestra en el formulario que el campo debe ser un número al momento de hacer clic fuera del campo.